# Representing chained methods and members Typescript through Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chaining

I am testing a node.js controller file using mocha and chai and i'm unable to mock out the response object in my test

### TestController.ts

```
export class TestController {

    static async getTest(req:any, res:any, next:object) {
        console.log("Test");
        //some code here
        res.status(200).json(result.rows);
    }
```

and this works perfectly fine when I call the API, returns the right response etc. But when I try to test this Controller, here is what I have for my test file

### Test.ts

```
it('Get Test method', async function () {
    let req = {params: {testid: 12345}};
    let res:any = {
      status: function() { }
    };

    res.json = '';
    let result = await TestController.getTest(req, res, Object);
});
```

I am not sure how to represent the response object here. If I just declare the variable res in the following way

```
let res:any;
```

I see the following error in my test

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

I am not sure how my response data structure res should be for making this test work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `sinon.stub().returnsThis()` to mock the `this` context, it allows you to call chain methods.

E.g.

`controller.ts`:

```js
export class TestController {
  static async getTest(req: any, res: any, next: object) {
    console.log('Test');
    const result = { rows: [] };
    res.status(200).json(result.rows);
  }
}
```

`controller.test.ts`:

```js
import { TestController } from './controller';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('61645232', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const req = { params: { testid: 12345 } };
    const res = {
      status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      json: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const next = sinon.stub();
    await TestController.getTest(req, res, next);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.status, 200);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.json, []);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  61645232
Test
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (14ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```